# How to use FragmentFactory with arguments at runtime?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager, android-fragmentfactory

Let's say i have a fragment with constructor that gets an argument at runtime depending on a network request for instance

```
class MyFragment(private val myArg: Int) : Fragment() {
   // Do layout and other stuff
}
```

I did a sample FragmentFactory to pass but my question is is there a better way to pass arguments especially when we have various fragments that need arguments in runtime?

```
class MyFragmentFactory private constructor() : FragmentFactory() {

    var myArg = 0

    override fun instantiate(classLoader: ClassLoader, className: String): Fragment {

        return when (className) {
            MyFragment::class.java.name -> MyFragment(myArg)
            else -> super.instantiate(classLoader, className)
        }
    }
}
```

There is a method of FragmentManager class

```
  public final FragmentTransaction replace(@IdRes int containerViewId,
        @NonNull Class<? extends Fragment> fragmentClass, @Nullable Bundle args) {
    return replace(containerViewId, fragmentClass, args, null);
}
```

how is this method used and can it be used with FragmentFactory, and how are arguments passed to the fragment using this method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot pass dynamic arguments to `FragmentManager` at runtime.
You still need to use bundle and arguments for the same.

For more details on this issue, you can track it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/136898243) and check google's [response](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/136898243#comment24) to it.

A brief blog about it can be found [here](https://proandroiddev.com/fragment-and-constructor-dependencies-3a4e6a0be152)